# Why the constructor of class isn't executed when using provider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

```
void main() {
  MainStream.init();
  runApp(
      MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            Provider(
              create: (context) => Test(context),
            ),
          ],
          child: MyApp()));
}

class Test {
  Test(BuildContext context) {
    print("Test");
  }
}
```

In this test code I would expect that "Test" is printed out when my App starts but it doesn't. What I'm doing wrong? I saw examples which initializes the providers like this.

Comment: Are you sure that `create` is called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the provider documentation the create callback is lazy-loaded so this is expected behavior. If you pass "lazy: false" it should work as you expected:

```
Provider(
    create: (context) => Test(context),
    lazy: false
),
```